# Distance Between Subsets in Connected Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Suppose $\langle X, d \rangle$ is a metric space.  For any two sets $F,G \subseteq X$, by abuse of notation define $d(F,G) = \inf \{ d(f,g): f \in F, g \in G \}$.

Let $\rho > 0$, $x \in X$, and $E \subseteq X$ be such that the open ball of radius $\rho$ centered at $x$ has non-empty intersection with both $E$ and its complement.  If $X$ is connected, does it follow that $d(B_{\rho}(x) \cap E, B_{\rho}(x) \cap E^c) = 0$, where $E^c$ is the complement of $E$ in $X$?

If the statement is false, are there obvious natural conditions that one could place on the metric space in question (rather than on the open ball centered at $x$) that guarantee that $d(B_{\rho}(x) \cap E, B_{\rho}(x) \cap E^c) = 0$?

Comment: That first notation is so common it is hardly an abuse.

Comment: It doesn't follow. Consider a space shaped roughly like a $U$, $E$ contained in the left stroke, and a large enough $\rho$.

Comment: Not in general. Let $X=(\{0,1\}\times\Bbb R)\cup\Bbb (\Bbb R\times\{0\})$, $E=\{1\}\times\Bbb R$ and $x=(0,2)$, $\rho=1.5$

Comment: Abuse of notation?  You are just extending the domain of $d$.

Comment: While it is standard notation, it is an abuse of notation as subsets of $X$ can also be elements of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples, Stefan and Daniel.  Here are two quick follow up questions.  Connectedness of the open ball is sufficient to guarantee the result in questions.  So:
1.  Are there obvious global constraints on a metric space that guarantee open balls will connected?  That was essentially my second question in the original post.  Clearly, if $X$ is a normed vector space, then it follows.  Are there other obvious natural properties?
2.  Did you consciously generate counterexamples by thinking of subspaces of the plane in which there would be disconnected open balls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexamples for connected spaces have already been given by Daniel Fischer and Stefan H.

It turns out that connectedness is somewhat tangential to the issue. The property you are after is inherited by dense subspaces, so it also applies to  $\mathbb{Q}^n$ for example. That means it makes sense to look for conditions
on the completion of $X$. A reasonable sufficient condition is that
the completion is a length space, because in a length space all open balls
are path-connected.